# How to verify this background-image in selenium

Tags: selenium, background-image

```
<div ng-class="highlightDev" style="position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;http://green.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; left: 24px; top: 294px; width: 20px; height: 20px;" ng-repeat="sensor in trashSensors" ng-hide="switchAlternate == 'off' &amp;&amp; sensor.alert == '#0bd189'" class="sample test" data-original-title="" title=""> </div>
```

How to verify this background-image: `url(quot;http://green.png&quot;);` image is present or not

Comment: If you found the answer, please post it as an answer and accept it so this question will get marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium you can only check the element existence in DOM. If you want to ensure that the image is physically visible / rendered properly on page, Selenium will not provide you with 100% reliability. If that's what you want to do though, you might want to check other projects for that purpose. For example Sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@style, 'background-image: url(quot;http://green.png&quot;);')]")).isdisplayed();
```

This will return true if the element is displayed.

Comment: Hello sai, i worked out with your code but again blocked.      WebElement mapgrey=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[contains(@style, 'background-image: url(&quot;http://grey.png&quot;);')]"));

Comment: Why there are two semi colans in url

Comment: one for &quot; and another one for close the style

Answer (score 0):

We Have to locate the class name first and then try with get attribute event like this

list - locate the div    list.getAttribute("style").contains("http://red.png")